# Why is the complexity of this nested for loop not $O(n^2)$?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, time-complexity, asymptotics

I have the following pseudo-code:

```
mystery(n):
if n <= 50 :
    for i = 1 ... n :
        for j = 1 ... n :
            print i*j
else :
    mystery(n-1)
```

For the following nested for loop:

```
for i = 1 ... n :
        for j = 1 ... n :
```

For every `i` in `n`, `j` iterates through `n` as many as `i` times. So, why is it that the complexity is not $O(n^2)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $n$ is bounded by $50$, which is simply a constant. Observe that when $n$ is larger than $50$, you simply have a recursive call. It's only when $n \leq 50$ that you go into the first portion of the if statement and execute the for-loops. Therefore, both nested loops take $\Theta(1)$ time. Hence the total time complexity of the mystery function is linear.

Note that $O(n^2)$ is technically correct, though not tight since $O(1) \subset O(n^2)$. The exact running time is $\Theta(1)$ as pointed above.

Comment: Should be O (n), since you _do_ make n-50 recursive calls.

Comment: I did say "Hence the total time complexity of the mystery function is linear."